# How to select a column that is not selectable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column in sql server that I need to select and I can not select but appear to exist.  Is it a read only column or some other issue?  Hopefully I added enough info here and I changed the name of my column and table to a generic name.

```
SELECT t.name as TName, c.name AS ColName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE upper(c.name) like '%MY_COLUMN_NAME%'

TName      ColName    
------     -----------
My_Table   My_Column
```

But when I try to select it, it says it doen't exist. Is there a workaround?

```
select My_Column from My_Table

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'My_Column'.
```

When I try with all the information I get this:

```
SELECT t.name as TName, c.name AS ColName, t.*, c.*
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE upper(c.name) like '%My_Column%'

TName                                                                                                                            ColName                                                                                                                          name                                                                                                                             object_id   principal_id schema_id   parent_object_id type type_desc                                                    create_date             modify_date             is_ms_shipped is_published is_schema_published lob_data_space_id filestream_data_space_id max_column_id_used lock_on_bulk_load uses_ansi_nulls is_replicated has_replication_filter is_merge_published is_sync_tran_subscribed has_unchecked_assembly_data text_in_row_limit large_value_types_out_of_row is_tracked_by_cdc lock_escalation lock_escalation_desc                                         is_filetable object_id   name                                                                                                                             column_id   system_type_id user_type_id max_length precision scale collation_name                                                                                                                   is_nullable is_ansi_padded is_rowguidcol is_identity is_computed is_filestream is_replicated is_non_sql_subscribed is_merge_published is_dts_replicated is_xml_document xml_collection_id default_object_id rule_object_id is_sparse is_column_set
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------- ---- ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------- ------------ ------------------- ----------------- ------------------------ ------------------ ----------------- --------------- ------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ----------------------- --------------------------- ----------------- ---------------------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------ ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------- ------------ ---------- --------- ----- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------- --------------------- ------------------ ----------------- --------------- ----------------- ----------------- -------------- --------- -------------
My_Table                                                                                                                         My_Column                                                                                                              My_Table                                                                                                                         1223935682  NULL         20          0                U    USER_TABLE                                                   2014-02-19 10:35:44.537 2017-02-11 12:48:13.037 0             0            0                   1                 NULL                     39                 0                 1               0             0                      0                  0                       0                           0                 0                            0                 0               TABLE                                                        0            1223935682  My_Column                                                                                                              7           104            376          1          1         0     NULL                                                                                                                             1           0              0             0           0           0             0             0                     0                  0                 0               0                 0                 0              0         0
```

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: what result do you get when you execute "Select * From Table" statement? does it show that column in the result?

Comment: How many rows does this return? select * from sys.tables where name = 'My_Table'

Comment: This is a tricky server b/c they are using server objects to attach another database and they didn't add all the schema to the attached/linked database.  So it only returned one row for the dbo schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have tables with the same name in different schemas that have different columns?

Your results look like it is a `bit` column, and that the `schema_id` is `20`, so I doubt it is the default schema (`dbo`). But I could be reading that wrong, as the values and headers look like they lost alignment.

```
select 
    TName = quotename(schema_name(t.schema_id))+'.'+quotename(t.name)
  , ColName = c.name
from sys.columns c
  inner join sys.tables t 
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name like '%My_Column%'
```

Comment: Wow... Yes. it has a schema called StateOfCalifornia with added column.  And one of them is my_column.  thx

Comment: To explain this better...  there are two table: One is in dbo schema and in the other is in StateOfCalifornia schema.  The dbo one is in dbo.My_Tables without My_Column existing and the StateOfCalifornia schema is with StateOfCalifornia.My_Tables existing.  *The table name is the same, the schemas are different.  I guess the idea if you are in California then you might need the extra column other you don't.

Answer (score 1):

It might me in a different schema.
Try to use the following query, as this will give you the schema name as well.

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_COLUMN';`

This assumption is made due to the fact that the schema_id in your last query is 0.

Comment: DO NOT use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view to determine the schema. It states right in the documentation that you should NOT use this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql However, I do agree that different schemas is likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: I tried it with Column_Name and it is a bit.  I should still be able to select that column from that table somehow?